# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError even though war file contains the jar containing the class

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, war

I have maven dependency to import an external project jar. The jar is imported in my project by Maven and is present in my Libraries->Maven Dependencies.
I access a static method of a class present inside this Jar from one of my classes. When I do Maven build and run the project in Tomcat that is configured inside my Eclipse, it runs fine and the class and its method is accessible.
But when I deploy the war file build by Maven to external Tomcat server, I get

```
14-May-2017 14:40:31.631 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [apple] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.apple.fruit.security.client.TokenManager] with root cause
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.apple.fruit.security.client.TokenManager
```

I accessed that war file and found that the war file contains that jar.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the jar in the war?

Comment: WEB-INF\lib\       All the jar are here at this path.